# ElasticBeanstalk Amazon Linux 2 Node not logging to web.stdout

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-linux-2

I've been upgrading to Amazon linux 2 recently and I'm now trying to debug my node application with the web.stdout logs. I was seeing them previously and now they aren't being shown. I can curl my node application as expected so I know it has to be running.

I've tried to restart my `amazon-cloudwatch-agent` since that is what is being used for logging and I've re-deployed my beanstalk application and it's still not showing them. I'm not sure why this would be happening.

Answer (score 3):

Well... I'm using a Procfile to handle my `npm run start:prod` command and in the Procfile I was using I had a different process_name being used. The correct way I needed to start my node app to have it log to the web.stdout log was to have it setup like this...

```
<process_name1>: <command1>
web: npm run start:prod
```

I didn't see anything that specifically stated to name the start command `web:` until reading the documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html),

"Elastic Beanstalk captures standard output and error streams from Procfile processes in log files. Elastic Beanstalk names the log files after the process and stores them in /var/log. For example, the web process in the preceding example generates logs named web-1.log and web-1.error.log for stdout and stderr, respectively."

Once I changed my `process_name1` to `web`, I started to see logs in the web.stdout log again.

+1 for having a helpful co-worker ask why I didn't name it `web`